# How Can I Implement Realtime Notification On My Php Page

Tags: javascript, php, html

**This Is My Home.Php** ,I Need To Display Realtime Notification From Database

```
<html>
<body>
<label>Notifications <?php echo "(".$notification.")"; ?>)</label>
//$notification Contain no. of Notifications From Database
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AJAX and setInterval would get you part way there. For close to true real time, you may be having to look at websockets.

Comment: which is More Secure?

Comment: currently i am using @Node Js . Here I have Another Problem. I Need to Execute a Query like:-   select * from tb_users where user_id="value from Php Session" . I need to Get the User_id from php Session to execute the Query. How can I do it ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `web socket` for real time notification. You can try `Ratchet` or `socket.io`.

Comment: what is the first step to do it using web socket?

Comment: @Krishnan Learning how to use web sockets

Comment: currently i am using @Node Js . Here I have Another Problem. I Need to Execute a Query like:- select * from tb_users where user_id="value from Php Session" . I need to Get the User_id from php Session to execute the Query. How can I do it ? :(